# Arranging matplotlib subplots into subgrids

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I want to make a plot in matplotlib with subplots arranged like so:

[image: Layout]

Where each of the colored squares represents a different subplot. How can I get matplotlib to make two subplots, one of which has several sub-subplots?

Comment: I found http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html handy for my work

Comment: @cgeroux: Expand that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `subplot()`:

```
pl.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
pl.subplot(1, 2, 1)
for axeid in (3, 4, 7, 8):
    pl.subplot(2, 4, axeid)
```

the output is:

[image]